# Azure function: Cannot find certificate with this thumbprint in the certificate

Tags: azure, function, powershell, sharepoint

I am creating azure function connecting to to execute PnP commands. I have created certificate as mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/tree/master/Samples/SharePoint.ConnectUsingAppPermissions). I am always getting `Cannot find certificate with this thumbprint in the certificate store.Exception             :Type`

Why this error is happening? Any settings need to be modified?
[image]

Comment: If you are running this in an Azure Function, how are you importing the certificate into the function worker's certificate store before execution?

Comment: Did you follow complete doc? Are you adding that SP in your function app? When does this throw error?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following steps

1. Create the self signed certificate

```
New-PnPAzureCertificate -OutPfx pnp.pfx -OutCert pnp.cer
```

2. Create Azure AD application
3. Configure permissions

   Office 365 SharePoint Online (Application Permission)

   - Sites.FullControl.All
   - TermStore.ReadWrite.All
   - User.ReadWriteAll
4. Upload your client certificate(cer file) to the AD application
   [image]
5. Create Function
6. Upload your pfx file to Azure function

```
az webapp config ssl upload --certificate-file "e:\cert\pnp.pfx"  --name "<function app name>" --resource-group ""  --certificate-password "" --query thumbprint --output tsv
```

7. Configure Function to allow  the function to read the certificate

```
az functionapp config appsettings set --name <app-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name> --settings WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES=<comma-separated-certificate-thumbprints>
```

8 function code

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Tenant <>.onmicrosoft.com -ClientId <the appid of the ad application> -Thumbprint <comma-separated-certificate-thumbprints> -Url https://<>.sharepoint.com
```

[image]