# How to connect to Exchange online in Azure function

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, exchange-server

I have tried to connect to Exchange online in azure function via CertificateThumbprint but i always got error

> "No certificate found"

i can connect local but when i deployed to azure function i cant connect
i use :

```
 Connect-ExchangeOnline -AppId <%App_id%> -CertificateThumbprint <%Thumbprint string of certificate%> -Organization "contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
```

so can anyone give me recomendation

Comment: Have you uploaded the certificate to ttl setting & created an application setting "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATE= thumbprint" of that particular certificate ?

Comment: Yes, i did it and i have same error.

Comment: Are you trying to call that application setting `$env:WEBSITE_LOAD_CERRTIFICATE` in your code?

Comment: No, i did not so i will try it thanks for replying

Comment: i tried but still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -AppId <%App_id%> -CertificateThumbprint <%Thumbprint string of certificate%> -Organization "contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
```

This cmdlet connects to Exchange Online in an unattended scripting scenario using a certificate thumbprint.

From this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/connect-exchangeonline?view=exchange-ps#example-4), I understood that:

Instead of passing `Thumbprint string value of certificate` in cmdlets, move the thumbprint to the application settings and retrieve it from the script using `$env:CERT_THUMBPRINT` .

Please refer this [SO Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68975497/using-the-exchangeonlinemanagement-powershell-module-inside-powershell-azure-fun) and [SO Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66386136/azure-function-cannot-find-certificate-with-this-thumbprint-in-the-certificate) where the cannot find certificate while connecting exchange online and other in azure functions are solved using few steps like uploading certificate via portal as well as defining the certificate string value in app settings.